# Need (Selenium webdriver + Junit) Sample test frame work code or the way how to run

Tags: selenium, junit, webdriver

I need a Selenium webdriver + Junit Sample test frame work.

where i can run the below things
1) Frame work should read the inputs/testcase id from config file/txt file
2) flexibility to run particular test case only when it fails.
3) Can be automated.

Currently my test cases are large number, if i use Junit TestSuite then more number of classes needs to be maintained, if i use Junit normal test case then i cant automate & cant run particular fail test case

Please help

Comment: Does it need to be Junit framework? My primary experience has been with TestNG - it uses a configuration file to determine what tests to run. As part of the test process, TestNG creates a configuration file that contains only the failing test cases, which can be run as-is.

Comment: Hi Bob, yes i need in Junit frame work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void test() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com);
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().equals("Google"));
}
```

That's it, easist test you can get. I would also recommend Maven for handling your dependencies, in this case your `pom.xml` would look like

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```